# Python + Selenium sendkeys on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, selenium, xpath

I keep trying to use sendkeys on an element but it keeps saying: `"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element is not visible"`.

The HTML code is:

```
<input class="form-control inspectletIgnore ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid-email-not-match ng-empty ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="email" ng-disabled="ad.isEditMode" required="" name="Email" ng-model="ad.Email.value" type="email">
```

I've tried to locate element by different XPaths:

```
//*[@id="email"] | //input[@ng-model = 'ad.Email.value']
```

Also tried to use JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('email').value='mail@mail.com'
```

None of them working. Any advice how to handle this? It's a big headache...

Comment: Which exact language you're using?

Comment: I'm using Python.

Comment: try `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_id("email")))`. Is it `1`?

Comment: Well it's not 1 , it's 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be 2 authorization forms on page - the first one is hidden. To handle visible input try:

```
driver.find_elements_by_id("email")[1]
```

Also if hidden form will be removed after some time, it might be better to use

```
driver.find_elements_by_id("email")[-1]
```

Comment: browser.find_element_by_id('email')[1].send_keys('blabla@blabla.com')

TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object does not support indexing
How I can solve this one ?

Comment: `browser.find_elements_by_id('email')[1].send_keys('blabla@blabla.com')`